# rails processing as HTML instead of JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to create a function with ajax to edit and update comments in a form.
my edit function is working without problems using ajax but when i try to update the comment, i get the error: *CommentsController#update is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []*

comments_controller

```
def update
    respond_to :js
    authorize @comment, :update?
    @comment.update(comment_params)


    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Commentaar is succesvol toegevoegd.'
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Commentaar is niet toegevoegd.'
    end      
end

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
end
```

update.js.erb

```
$("#comment-ajax-<%= @comment.id %>").html("<%= j render @comment %>");
```

_comment.html.erb

```
<% if policy(comment).edit? %>
   <%= link_to 'edit', [:edit, comment.fabmoment, comment], remote: true, 'data-type' => 'script' %>
<% end %>
```

comment form

```
<%= simple_form_for [fabmoment, comment] do |f| %>
    <!-- Input -->
    <%= f.input_field :text, rows: 4 %>
    <%= f.label :text %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you also show code of your form from view?

Comment: Could you also add the request params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the form is being submitted as 'text/html'. Try adding `remote: true` to the actual form instead of the `link_to`.

Comment: thank so much ! we've been working on this problem for 2 days straight, yet the answer was this simple haha